Finding the relative spectrum of a pushforward
Let $f: A \to B$ be an isogeny of abelian varieties (i.e. a surjective homomorphism whose kernel is finite as a scheme). What is the relative spectrum of $f_* \mathcal{O}_A$?
My first problem is figuring out $f_* \mathcal{O}_A$: a natural guess would be $\mathcal{O}_B$, but this is not the case in general since $f$ can have disconnected fibers.

The morphism $f$ is affine, therefore the relative (over $B$) spectrum of $f_*\mathcal{O}_A$ is $A$.

Could you please elaborate on why $f$ is affine?

I think I just got it; is it because $f$ has finite fibers, hence finite, hence affine?

Finite fibers only means "quasi-finite", but together with properness it implies finiteness. And indeed, finite maps are affine.
